# columns-rows not moving down when screen size is small/mobile screen?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the rows in a `reactjs` `html` `bootstrap5` page to be responsive. i.e. I want the column in the row to move down/become vertical when screen size is small.

I thought this would be accomplished on its own using samples from: [grid system documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/)

I have tried a lot of different things but none of them solve the issue. I assumed this would work easily with bootstrap 5. I must be missing something.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* For mobile phones: */
    [class*="col-"] {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

main {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to right top, #FFFFFF, #D3D3D3);
}

.navbar {
    /*background: #e6e7e8;*/
    background: #D3D3D3;
}

.card {
    background: inherit;
    backdrop-filter: blur();
}

.card:before {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2000px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

/*!* Make app full screen *!*/
/*#app {*/
/*    height: 100vh;*/
/*    width: 100vw;*/
/*}*/
/* css remove whitespace from above background */
.remove-whitespace {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    width: 5vw;
}


.chartBox {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 525px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/5/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/custom.css">

<div class="container-flex">
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<div class="chartBox" style="position: relative; height: 525px;">
<canvas role="img" id="line-chart" style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 525px; width: 960px;" width="960" height="525">
</canvas>
<div style=""></div></div></div>

<div class="col">

<div class="card card-body mt-4 mb-4 text-center mx-auto"><h2 class="text-center">Add</h2>

<form>
<div class="form-group text-center">

<label for="country">Country</label><select name="country" id="country" class="form-control text-center"><option value="">Select the country...</option><option value="India">India</option><option value="United States of America">United States of America</option></select></div>

</form>
```

Comment: Why are you creeating new properties for `[class*="col-"]`? That's not how Bootstrap is intended to be used. Use the class from Bootstrrap instead.

Answer (score 0):

Few issues in your snippet.
If you want a column to take 100% of the width on mobile and less on a different resolution, Bootstrap handle it for you, you shouldn't re-write something like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* For mobile phones: */
    [class*="col-"] {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Stick to the Bootstrap classes:

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm"></div>
```

Here the column will take 100% of the width on mobile, then it will share the width with the other column starting from the breakpoint `sm`, `>=576px`

You also enforce width:

```
.chartBox {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 525px;
}
```

```
<canvas role="img" id="line-chart" style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 525px; width: 960px;" width="960" height="525"></div>
```

They can break the layout if you don't add a `max-width`, something like `max-width: 100%;`

Please see an updated snippet that should solve some of your issues:

```css
main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, #FFFFFF, #D3D3D3);
}

.navbar {
  background: #D3D3D3;
}

.card {
  background: inherit;
  backdrop-filter: blur();
}

.card:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2000px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

.remove-whitespace {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  width: 5vw;
}

.chartBox {
  height: 525px;
}

canvas {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/5/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm">
      <div class="chartBox" style="position: relative; height: 525px;">
        <canvas role="img" id="line-chart" style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 525px; width: 960px;" width="960" height="525">
</canvas>
        <div style=""></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm">
      <div class="card card-body mt-4 mb-4 text-center mx-auto">
        <h2 class="text-center">Add</h2>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group text-center">
            <label for="country">Country</label>
            <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control text-center">
              <option value="">Select the country...</option>
              <option value="India">India</option>
              <option value="United States of America">United States of America</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

And don't forget to read [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/) to learn how to use the grid system they  provide.